# Aggregate column by condition

Tags: postgresql

I have to write an Uptime Report for a Homepage. In the table that is available for me I have 2 columns. The first one is the status of the Homepage (0 is offline and 1 is online) and the second one is the duration of this status in seconds. An example table might look like this:

```
-------------------------
|  Status  |  Duration  |  
-------------------------
|  0       |  50        |
-------------------------
|  1       |  10        |
-------------------------
|  1       |  20        |
-------------------------
|  1       |  50        |
-------------------------
|  0       |  50        |
-------------------------
|  0       |  50        |
-------------------------
|  1       |  20        |
-------------------------
```

This does not look that nice in my report because the same stati should be aggregated into one row and not be shown as multiple rows like this:

```
-------------------------
|  Status  |  Duration  |  
-------------------------
|  0       |  50        |
-------------------------
|  1       |  80        |
-------------------------
|  0       |  100       |
-------------------------
|  1       |  20        |
-------------------------
```

Is there a way to achieve this with PostgreSQL?

Comment: try using `group by`

Comment: Use `group by duration`

Comment: You would need another column in the table, either a sequence of number or timestamp to indicate the progress of status. Database does  not store rows in any particular order. So, without such column, there is no way to know the  change in the value of  status.

Answer (score 1):

As I said already, you would need an `id/datetime` column to track the progress.
Only then would you be able to use `LEAD/LAG` function or [*TABIBITOSAN*](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/ganotedp/tabibito-san-the-traveler-technique-in-sql-080216) method for this scenario.

[SQL Fiddle](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/ganotedp/tabibito-san-the-traveler-technique-in-sql-080216)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (id INT,Status int, Duration int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (id,Status, Duration)
VALUES
    (1,0, 50),
    (2,1, 10),
    (3,1, 20),
    (4,1, 50),
    (5,0, 50),
    (6,0, 50),
    (7,1, 20)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT STATUS
    ,Sum(duration)
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) - row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY id
            ) AS seq
    FROM t
    ) s
GROUP BY STATUS
    ,seq
ORDER BY max(id)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/81b1a/9/0)**:

```
| status | sum |
|--------|-----|
|      0 |  50 |
|      1 |  80 |
|      0 | 100 |
|      1 |  20 |
```

Comment: Plus for Tabibitosan method, that's very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation can be achieved by using window functions and grouping:

```
select max(status) status, sum(duration) duration from (
          select status, duration, sum(case when status <> par then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) wf from ( 
            select id, status, duration, lag(status, 1) over () par from test
          ) a order by id
      ) a group by wf order by wf
```

You just need to properly set your ordering in window function.

Test data:

```
create table test (status int, duration int, id bigserial primary key);

insert into test (status, duration) values (0, 50);
insert into test (status, duration) values (1, 10);
insert into test (status, duration) values (1, 20);
insert into test (status, duration) values (1, 50);
insert into test (status, duration) values (0, 50);
insert into test (status, duration) values (0, 50);
insert into test (status, duration) values (1, 20);
```

Output like you wanted.